# Asp.net based image editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am looking for an image editor which can be incorporated into my asp.net application. My scenario is user select image from the image gallery and opens with the image editor, after edit the image and save it back on the web server. Image editor must have a paint brush. Crop and resizing of the image is not necessary.

I am looking for such a tools for the last 3 days, but not able to find any. I will go for paid software also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on the browser, you will need to use something like flash. There are plenty of image editing components in flash - here is [one](http://software.informer.com/getfree-flash-client-side-image-editor/).

See the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174504/client-side-image-processing) SO quesion (Client-side image processing).

Comment: Thanks. Yes i want to edit the image on browser and after edit saved it back on our application webserver.I will help me if you will write about the specific tools that u have worked and integrate on your application..

Comment: @purnang - I don't have experience with these tools, I was outlining a general approach.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Flash editors specified by Oded,
  You can look at the Javascript + SVG based online image editor [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/). Its free.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Appriciate your help.But i could not find the way how to imparot image to svg-edit? Can you please give me some idea how will I integrated my asp.net applocation to svg-edit?

Comment: @purnang, i also dont have real time experience with svg-edit.. But you ca n just download the library. since this is Javascript, you can easily understand and tweek into meet ur needs..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at picnik  http://www.picnik.com/  .

Comment: Why doesn't picnik solve your problem? It does exactly all you specified you need the image editor to do. You would have to explain what else you need it to do that picnik does not do.