# Embed text and Image & then make it as a single Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, client-side

I have an Image; say for example "an appreciation certificate". only the name of the person in the certificate changes.

when the user enters his name in the textbox, the name on the certificate should have the text  he just entered.

I can do this by just overlapping the text on to the image.but

the real problem is:

after he enters his name; the text and the certificate image be combined and rendered as a single image on the client side.

this has to be done in jquery/javascript **without serverside code or HTML5 canvas**

Comment: Have a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174504/client-side-image-processing).

Comment: If you don't want to use canvas or any server-side code, it's not possible.
(Unless you are willing to use flash, but some mobile browsers, or people that don't have flash installed, won't be able to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple but short this (outputting a physical image out of divs) is NOT possible with pure jQuery/Javascript. It is possible through HTML5 canvas use, although a bit raw, and there are numerous of good php libraries (imagick, gd) that will make this look like a breeze.