# Javascript convert the current page to canvas so I can manipulate it

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

is there a way to convert/copy an html page into a canvas so I can manipulate it graphically.

I want to warp the page in 3D so it looks like it is wrapping around the user's head.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you want to do this on the client side?

Comment: Hopefully yes, but could do it server side and ajax it in if necessary

Comment: You could use DOM2Canvas, but it won't be exact.

Comment: Maybe the combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174504 will do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) helps your.

Check the next [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/182344). It has more detailed explanation.