# Which programming langage should I use to process images online?

Tags: mobile, image-processing, web, client-side

I'd like to learn to create a website with processing on the client side.
Here are my goals:
 - The program would look like something like Picasa or Lightroom. It means processing lot of pictures in a row
 - I'd like the client to download the "image processor" to avoid uploading plenty of pictures on the server (which is slow and frustrating IMHO).
 - I also have in mind to create a mobile version of the website

I don't know a lot about internet programming languages but here are my thoughts at the moment:

1. Flash: I think it would do, but I don't like it (not portable enough from what I read)
2. Java: This is the one I am thinking of at the moment. But I don't like the idea of asking users to download a third party if they don't have it.
3. HTML5 + Javascript: I don't what it means regarding Javascript capabilities. Would it be a pain?
4. Python, Ruby on Rail, C#: I don't know what it means to use them for web programming. I already used Python put as scripting language.

There are for sure other technologies that I am not aware of. Feel free to propose anything else that is mainstream enough to get good support on the internet :)!

Thank you for your help!

I hope you won't think it is a duplicate. I made some search and found this for ex:
[Client-side image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174504/client-side-image-processing) 
 => But they already have their core processing since I have nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern web browsers support html5 & javascript out of the box - older ones at least have support for javascript unless support for something truely ancient is desired - so considering the compatibility it should be the best one of these alternatives.

Flash needs a flash-plugin and a Java applet needs a jre-plugin.
Have never seen the 4th choice in client-based web-applications really, so not sure about how that would be done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am going to have a look at javascript then. Thanks!